# ng-options Default Value from JSON

Tags: angularjs, html

I have been toying around with a modal form, the form works great to submit data, but now I need the form to edit data. So I want to populate the form from a callback from the server. The structure of the form is as follows:

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group modalContent">
   <label for="manufacturer">MANUFACTURER</label>
   <select class="form-control" id="manufacturersList"
      ng-model="form.manufacturers" required
      ng-options="man.manufacturer for man in manufacturers | orderBy:'manufacturer'"></select>
</div>
```

AngularJS:

```
$scope.form = {
   //The value will be the value from the callback
   "manufacturers": "Acer"
}
```

EDIT: CALL BACK

```
    {"status":{"error":"none","code":200,"description":"none","message":"success"},"manufacturers":[{"manID":"2",
"manufacturer":"Acer"},{"manID":"3","manufacturer":"Honeywell"},{"manID":"11","manufacturer":"HP"},{"manID":"9","manufacturer":"Juniper"},{"manID":"1","manufacturer":"Lenovo"},{"manID":"6","manufacturer":"Logitech"},{"manID":"8","manufacturer":"Netgear"},{"manID":"7","manufacturer":"Other"},{"manID":"10","manufacturer":"StarTech"},{"manID":"5","manufacturer":"Viewsonic"},{"manID":"4","manufacturer":"Zebra"}]}
```

Shouldn't this populate the value in the `<SELECT>`?

Comment: Do you mean that `$scope.form.manufactures` is actually an array of strings (`['Acer']`)?

Comment: Yes? I'm sorry, I still fairly new to Angular concept. `$scope.form.manufactures` is an array of strings. Once the form is submitted it will have the `id` of the option associated with it. But the ID is not given during the call back, only the name.

Comment: I've updated my code and supplied the callback.

Comment: After looking at it, it is an array of objects not strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-model` points to the variable that holds the selected value.
And according to the syntax you used in `ng-options` you should place `manufactures` in `$scope` directly.

```
<select class="form-control" id="manufacturersList"
  ng-model="selectedManufacturer" required
  ng-options="man for man in manufacturers | orderBy:'manufacturer'">
</select>

$scope.manufacturers = ["Acer", 'HP', 'Toshiba', 'Lenovo', 'ASUS'];
```

Example in [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/IT8wQTjzZTqPrmIxwSnM)

Hope this helps

Comment: I will accept this answer as correct, since it correct given what information was submitted. However, in my instance, I was trying to pass data to two separate controllers. I corrected the issue I was having and I was able to get the code to work.